# Settings are missing after upgrading from 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.04

So I guess the main problem here is Broken packages and I don't know how to fix them. Here's why I think so.
I tried to install gnome-control-center to get my settings button back:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: sane-utils (>= 1.0.29-0ubuntu5)
     E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I tried installing packages with one of those commands:

```
sudo apt-get install [package name]
sudo apt install --reinstall [package name]
```

But I'm getting the same error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsane : Depends: libsnmp35 (>= 5.8+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And etc.

I also tried to install packages using Synaptic, but it said I have broken packages. So I pressed Edit > Fix Broken Packages. Here what I've got:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```